# Long to wide format by collecting multiple ID columns in R which have different values

Tags: r, reshape

I know there are a lot of guides on moving from long to wide format. For instance, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

However, I believe I have a unique case, or at least a case that I cannot find on stack overflow with an answer, though maybe I do not have the right language for my question. I will depict my problem with data. I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
>  my.df <- data.frame(ID=rep(c("A","B","C"), 3), TIME=rep(1:9, each=1), X=1:9, Y=10:18)
>  my.df
  ID TIME X  Y
1  A    1 1 10
2  B    2 2 11
3  C    3 3 12
4  A    4 4 13
5  B    5 5 14
6  C    6 6 15
7  A    7 7 16
8  B    8 8 17
9  C    9 9 18
```

I want to move from long to wide format, but I importantly want to keep the unique information contained in the time column and do not want it to spread out into a column name.  I want to create multiple time columns where there is a duplicate of ID, and store the corresponding X and Y data next to that column.

See below desired output:

```
> my.df <- data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C"), TIME_1=c(1,2,3),X_1 = c(1,2,3), Y_1= c(10,11,12),
+                     TIME_2 = c(4,5,6),X_2 = c(4,5,6),Y_2 = c(13,14,15),
+                     TIME_3 = c(7,8,9),X_3 = c(7,8,9),Y_3 = c(16,17,18))
> my.df
  ID TIME_1 X_1 Y_1 TIME_2 X_2 Y_2 TIME_3 X_3 Y_3
1  A      1   1  10      4   4  13      7   7  16
2  B      2   2  11      5   5  14      8   8  17
3  C      3   3  12      6   6  15      9   9  18
```

Is this possible?

My real dataframe is much bigger, and the TIME column contains unique dates that I can't put into a column name, which is why I want to keep that information stored in new columns.  I know that I only have at most 4 duplicate ID values, so I am not worried about creating an exorbitant amount of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `reshape` from base R. The `ave` identifies the three consequent `seq`uences in example data.

```
reshape(transform(my.df, t2=with(my.df, ave(TIME, ID, FUN=seq))), idvar=c("ID"),
        timevar=c("t2"), direction="wide")
#   ID TIME.1 X.1 Y.1 TIME.2 X.2 Y.2 TIME.3 X.3 Y.3
# 1  A      1   1  10      4   4  13      7   7  16
# 2  B      2   2  11      5   5  14      8   8  17
# 3  C      3   3  12      6   6  15      9   9  18
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(my.df), ID ~ rowid(ID), value.var = c("TIME", "X", "Y"))
#   ID TIME_1 TIME_2 TIME_3 X_1 X_2 X_3 Y_1 Y_2 Y_3
#1:  A      1      4      7   1   4   7  10  13  16
#2:  B      2      5      8   2   5   8  11  14  17
#3:  C      3      6      9   3   6   9  12  15  18
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
my.df %>% 
    mutate(ind = rowid(ID)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = ind, values_from = c(TIME, X, Y))
# A tibble: 3 x 10
#  ID    TIME_1 TIME_2 TIME_3   X_1   X_2   X_3   Y_1   Y_2   Y_3
#  <fct>  <int>  <int>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 A          1      4      7     1     4     7    10    13    16
#2 B          2      5      8     2     5     8    11    14    17
#3 C          3      6      9     3     6     9    12    15    18
```

If we need the columns to be ordered in a specific way

```
my.df %>% 
     mutate(ind = rowid(ID)) %>% 
     pivot_wider(names_from = ind, values_from = c(TIME, X, Y)) %>%
     select(ID, order(readr::parse_number(names(.)[-1])) + 1)
# A tibble: 3 x 10
#  ID    TIME_1   X_1   Y_1 TIME_2   X_2   Y_2 TIME_3   X_3   Y_3
#  <fct>  <int> <int> <int>  <int> <int> <int>  <int> <int> <int>
#1 A          1     1    10      4     4    13      7     7    16
#2 B          2     2    11      5     5    14      8     8    17
#3 C          3     3    12      6     6    15      9     9    18
```

Comment: Using the example from dcast gets me an error: Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : 
  recursive indexing failed at level 2
In addition: Warning message:
In if (!(value.var %in% names(data))) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: @WillGorman I showed 2 methods that works on your example showed. and that too efficient

Comment: Thanks @akrun, I did also try the second example, however it appears I need the development version of the tidyverse installed and I was having trouble getting that version onto my system. pivot_wider must be a new feature not yet released.

Comment: @WillGorman `pivot_wider/pivot_longer` is already present in the latest CRAN vesion of tidyr,  I used `packageVersion('data.table')#
[1] ‘1.12.8’` and `packageVersion('tidyr')#
[1] ‘1.0.0’`